# Drush not fully installed

Tags: drush

I have installed Drush 8.2.3 globally on a Lubuntu 18.04 image. This was done without Composer (I used the default install instructions [here](http://docs.drush.org/en/8.x/install/))

However, if I run `drush topic` and select any topic number from the list I get

```
phar:///usr/local/bin/drush/examples/sync_via_http.drush.inc: No such file or directory
more: stat of phar:///usr/local/bin/drush/examples/sync_via_http.drush.inc failed: No such file or directory
```

What gives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue - [Topic command does not work when using Phar](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/issues/2583). Searching the [issue queue](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/issues) is always recommended. Since the current version is Drush 9, I don't expect this to be fixed.

Comment: thank you for pointing out the issue queue, I will in the future.